# Get id's of each item in array and append to each item in option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-select

Apologies for any incorrect use of terminology, I am new to Javascript but hopefully I can explain the outcome I am expecting to help to answer my question.

In my code below, I have an array of `dates` in which the output is...

```
["25/08/2016", "24/08/2016", "23/08/2016", "22/08/2016", "21/08/2016", "20/08/2016", "19/08/2016", "18/08/2016", "17/08/2016"]
```

I then loop through these dates and append each date to a html select option, the output is as follows...

```
<select id="dayConstraintList" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="25/08/2016">25/08/2016</option>
    <option value="24/08/2016">24/08/2016</option>
    <option value="23/08/2016">23/08/2016</option>
    <option value="22/08/2016">22/08/2016</option>
    <option value="21/08/2016">21/08/2016</option>
    <option value="20/08/2016">20/08/2016</option>
    <option value="19/08/2016">19/08/2016</option>
    <option value="18/08/2016">18/08/2016</option>
    <option value="17/08/2016">17/08/2016</option>
</select>
```

Below is my current code

```
var dates = [],
    end = moment(endDate),
    dif = moment(endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').diff(moment(startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'days');

if(dif <= 0) {
    return;
}

for(var i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
    dates.push(end.subtract(1,'d').format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
}

var option = '';
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    option += '<option value="' + dates[i] + '">' + dates[i] + '</option>';
}
console.log(dates);
$('#dayConstraintList').empty();
$('#dayConstraintList').append(option);
```

This is the outcome I expect, how can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated?

```
<select id="dayConstraintList" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="0">25/08/2016</option>
    <option value="1">24/08/2016</option>
    <option value="2">23/08/2016</option>
    <option value="3">22/08/2016</option>
    <option value="4">21/08/2016</option>
    <option value="5">20/08/2016</option>
    <option value="6">19/08/2016</option>
    <option value="7">18/08/2016</option>
    <option value="8">17/08/2016</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just change `value="' + dates[i] + '"` to `value="' + i + '"`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, can't believe it was as easy as that, I was overthinking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this part of code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    option += '<option value="' + dates[i] + '">' + dates[i] + '</option>';
}
```

By :

```
for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    option += '<option value="' + i + '">' + dates[i] + '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you change

```
<option value="' + dates[i] + '">' + dates[i] + '</option>
```

to

```
<option value="' + i + '">' + dates[i] + '</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this job as follows;

```js
var dates = ["25/08/2016", "24/08/2016", "23/08/2016", "22/08/2016", "21/08/2016", "20/08/2016", "19/08/2016", "18/08/2016", "17/08/2016"],
    selel = document.getElementById("dayConstraintList");
    
selel.appendChild(dates.map(d => {var opel = document.createElement("option"); opel.value = d; opel.textContent = d; return opel})
                       .reduce((df,opel) => (df.appendChild(opel), df),document.createDocumentFragment()));
```

```html
<select id="dayConstraintList" class="form-control input-lg">
</select>
```